# Can I run AWG 3-way switch wire in same SCH80 conduit as my feeder cable?

Tags: code-compliance, underground

I’m about to pull 200’ of 2/0 AL THHN from one of my branch panels on my home out to a sub-panel in my new backyard shop.  It occurred to me that it would be a good idea to wire a 3-way switch for the LED floodlights on the shop building, having one of the switches located in my home.

The floodlight circuit will originate and terminate in the shop, with “travelers” going to my house.

Is this ok to run in the same PVC conduit as my 2/0 cables, there is ample room for 3x12-14AWG.

Barring any objections to the idea above, any suggestions for alternate wire colors on the traveler circuit to my house?

Comment: Just to clarify, you are using *individual wires*, not 2/0 **cables**, right?

Comment: How much current are you planning to run over that 2/0 Al?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's fine.

Pick anything from the hot colors [black brown red orange yellow blue purple pink...] (NOT green, white, grey/gray) for your travelers, or use whatever one color you have as much as you need and put tape or colored heat-shrink tubing on two of them for ID. So it could all be black, with one small black taped blue and one small black taped purple - or blue twice, or...

More colors is conceptually nice, but reality is that if you're buying 500 feet of each color and not using 300 feet of it, it gets expensive if you don't have some other job to use it up.

Comment: Persnickety folks in telecom have no pink, only rose, and no grey/gray, only slate, but that does not seem to apply to power folks. Purple may also be violet. And aqua is a usual color - if you could find that in THHN, it could be hot.